# Mostrar ' gif cargando ' mientras descargo un archivo con VueJS (axios)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, archivo, axios

tengo el siguiente componente:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-12 text-center">
               <button  :class="{'disabled':loading}" :href="url_download_all_compressed_files" @click.prevent="loading = true" @click="downloadCompressedFiles" class="btn btn-warning"  title="Descargar todos los archivo en carpeta comprimida."><i class="far fa-file-archive"></i></button>

            </div>
            <div class="col-12">
                <p v-show="loading">Cargando...</p>
                <!-- <gif-loading style="position:fixed; top: 45%;left: 45%; top:30%; z-index:2;" :show="loading"></gif-loading> -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 text-center">
                <chart-donut class="my-4" :size_disk_used="size_disk_used" :data_param="data"></chart-donut>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props:[
            'size_disk_used',
            'data',
            'url_list_files',
            'url_upload_files',
            'url_download_all_compressed_files',
            'url_delete_all'
        ],
        data(){
            return{
                loading:false
            }
        },
        methods:{
            downloadCompressedFiles(){
                this.loading = true;
                let that = this;
                console.log('loading ='+this.loading);
                axios.get(this.$props.url_download_all_compressed_files, { responseType: 'blob' })
                    .then(response => {
                        const blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: 'application/zip' })
                        const link = document.createElement('a');
                        link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                        link.click();
                        URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href);
                        that.loading = false;
                        console.log('loading = '+this.loading);
                        console.log('response');
                        console.log(response);
                    }).catch(that.loading = false)
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

El botón  llama a la función  `downloadCompressedFiles()` para descargar el archivo, lo hace bien. Pero tengo una variable en data llamada `loading` como un flag para mostrar u ocultar un parrafo/gif lo que sea. Pero no se muestra nunca, he hecho unos `console.log` de la var `loading` y si se cambia el valor pero por alguna razón no es reactivo el cambio. El fichero se descarga y todo, solo que no se muestra el `cargando..`.

Lo que tiene de especial esta llamada asincrona es que retorna un archivo. No se si eso altera su reactividad.

La parte **backend** (Laravel) es esta, por si esta influyendo en algo:

```
public function downloadSingleFile(Request $request)
    {
        $fileId = $request->file_id;
        // $file = Fichero::find($fileId);
        $user = auth()->user();
        $file = $user->ficheros()->find($fileId);
        $pathFile = public_path('storage\\ficheros\\'.$user->getRootDir().'\\'.$file->nombre_hash);

        $owned = $user->id === $file->user_id ? true:false;

        if (file_exists($pathFile) and $owned) {
            return response()->download($pathFile);
        }
            return response()->json([false]);



    }
```